# Unintentional destruction of php array element?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

The following piece of php code will destroy the last element of the array

```
<?php
$arr = array('A','B','C','D','E');
foreach ($arr as &$val) {}
foreach ($arr as $val) {}
print_r($arr);
?>
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [2] => C
    [3] => D
    [4] => D
)
```

The code can be fixed by calling `unset($val);` between the two `foreach` statements.

Why is the last element destroyed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This blogpost](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/141-References-and-foreach.html) explains it better than I ever could. You should also check out [this bug report](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=29992) at PHP.net.

Comment: That answer couldn't be much better! Thank you very much.