# Strange behavior of foreach when using reference: foreach ($a as &$v) { ... }

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

```
<?php
  $a = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');

  foreach ($a as &$v) { }
  foreach ($a as $v) { }

  print_r($a);
?>
```

I think it's a normal program but this is the output I am getting:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => c
)
```

Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: What does *"i think, its normal prog but web i saw op.........then ....ahh wat is it"* mean?

Comment: i'm wondering!!! Why get this result?? :)

Comment: @Bart Kiers: He seems in a daze.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unintentional destruction of php array element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966352/unintentional-destruction-of-php-array-element)

Comment: This is the best explanation for this behavior: http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/141-References-and-foreach.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange behaviour after loop by reference - Is this a PHP bug?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220399/strange-behaviour-after-loop-by-reference-is-this-a-php-bug)

Comment: This question is now [discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360250/3151675).

Comment: The PHP manual recommends calling `unset($v);` after the first foreach loop to avoid this problem. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 115, accepted):

This is well-documented PHP behaviour
See the [warning](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) on the foreach page of php.net

> **Warning**
>
> Reference of a *$value* and the last array element remain even after the *foreach* loop. It is recommended to destroy it by unset().

```
$a = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');

foreach ($a as &$v) { }
unset($v);
foreach ($a as $v) { }

print_r($a);
```

**EDIT**

Attempt at a step-by-step guide to what is actually happening here

```
$a = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
foreach ($a as &$v) { }   // 1st iteration $v is a reference to $a[0] ('a')
foreach ($a as &$v) { }   // 2nd iteration $v is a reference to $a[1] ('b')
foreach ($a as &$v) { }   // 3rd iteration $v is a reference to $a[2] ('c')
foreach ($a as &$v) { }   // 4th iteration $v is a reference to $a[3] ('d')

                          // At the end of the foreach loop,
                          //    $v is still a reference to $a[3] ('d')

foreach ($a as $v) { }    // 1st iteration $v (still a reference to $a[3]) 
                          //    is set to a value of $a[0] ('a').
                          //    Because it is a reference to $a[3], 
                          //    it sets $a[3] to 'a'.
foreach ($a as $v) { }    // 2nd iteration $v (still a reference to $a[3]) 
                          //    is set to a value of $a[1] ('b').
                          //    Because it is a reference to $a[3], 
                          //    it sets $a[3] to 'b'.
foreach ($a as $v) { }    // 3rd iteration $v (still a reference to $a[3]) 
                          //    is set to a value of $a[2] ('c').
                          //    Because it is a reference to $a[3], 
                          //    it sets $a[3] to 'c'.
foreach ($a as $v) { }    // 4th iteration $v (still a reference to $a[3]) 
                          //    is set to a value of $a[3] ('c' since 
                          //       the last iteration).
                          //    Because it is a reference to $a[3], 
                          //    it sets $a[3] to 'c'.
```

Comment: @Manish Trivedi: See the **Warning** part for why this is happening. There's nothing wrong with your program.

Comment: Very good explanation! Thank you :D I have to remember that one as a reference/dupe, all other answers about reference with foreach doesn't explain it as good as you did here!

Comment: In your `unset($v);`, why is `$v` accessible outside the scope of foreachs? :o

Comment: @nawfal - don't understand the question.... PHP local variable scope is within a function, not simply within a loop

Comment: @MarkBaker thank you. You answered my question. Just coming to grips with PHP idiosyncrasies :)

Comment: Great answer! Glad you mentioned the workaround of adding `unset($v);` after the first foreach loop.

Answer (score 3):

The first
foreach loop does not make any change to the array, just as we would expect.
However, it does cause `$v` to be assigned a reference to each of `$a`’s elements,
so that, by the time the first loop is over, `$v` is, in fact, a reference to `$a[2]`.

As soon as the second loop starts, `$v` is now assigned the value of each
element. However, `$v` is already a reference to `$a[2];` therefore, any value
assigned to it will be copied automatically into the last element of the array!

Thus, during the first iteration, `$a[2]` will become zero, then one, and then
one again, being effectively copied on to itself. To solve this problem, you
should always unset the variables you use in your by-reference foreach
loops—or, better yet, avoid using the former altogether.

Answer (score -1):

It is not necessary that the reference variable is the loop variable. For example (this may look contrived, but of course is an oversimplification of a program of mine),

```
$list = [ 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four' ] ;
$results = [] ;
foreach ($list as $item) {
    $newitem = $item ;
    $results[] = &$newitem ;
#    unset($newitem) ;
}
var_dump($results) ;
```

prints

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  &string(4) "four"
  [1]=>
  &string(4) "four"
  [2]=>
  &string(4) "four"
  [3]=>
  &string(4) "four"
}
```

since every element of `$results` points to `$newitem`, which is *the same variable* at each iteration, and *at each iteration* is changed to point at the "current" element of list – so at the end it points to the last.

The commented `unset()` fixes the program, ensuring we have a "fresh" `$newitem` at each iteration, and the summary is, *beware the scope of references!*