# PHP pointer and variable conflict

Tags: php, pointers

I have a question about PHP and the use of pointers and variables.

The following code produces something I wouldn't have expected:

```
<?php
$numbers = array('zero', 'one', 'two', 'three');

foreach($numbers as &$number)
{
  $number = strtoupper($number);
}

print_r($numbers);

$texts = array();
foreach($numbers as $number)
{
  $texts[] = $number;
}

print_r($texts);
?>
```

The output is the following

```
Array
(
    [0] => ZERO
    [1] => ONE
    [2] => TWO
    [3] => THREE
)
Array
(
    [0] => ZERO
    [1] => ONE
    [2] => TWO
    [3] => TWO
)
```

Notice the 'TWO' appearing twice in the second array.

It seems that there is a conflict between the two foreach loops, each declaring a $number variable (once by reference and the second by value).

But why ? And why does it affect only the last element in the second foreach ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange behavior Of foreach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969243/strange-behavior-of-foreach)

Comment: Please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969243/strange-behavior-of-foreach/4969518#4969518 for an in-depth explanation of this behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key point is that PHP does not have pointers. It has [references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php), which is a similar but different concept, and there are some subtle differences.

If you use [var_dump()](http://php.net/var_dump) instead of print_r(), it's easier to spot:

```
$collection = array(
    'First',
    'Second',
    'Third',
);

foreach($collection as &$item){
    echo $item . PHP_EOL;
}

var_dump($collection);

foreach($collection as $item){
    var_dump($collection);
    echo $item . PHP_EOL;
}
```

... prints:

```
First
Second
Third
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "First"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "Second"
  [2]=>
  &string(5) "Third"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "First"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "Second"
  [2]=>
  &string(5) "First"
}
First
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "First"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "Second"
  [2]=>
  &string(6) "Second"
}
Second
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "First"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "Second"
  [2]=>
  &string(6) "Second"
}
Second
```

Please note the `&` symbol that's left in the last array item.

To sum up, whenever you use references in a loop, it's good practice to remove them at the end:

```
<?php

$collection = array(
    'First',
    'Second',
    'Third',
);

foreach($collection as &$item){
    echo $item . PHP_EOL;
}
unset($item);

var_dump($collection);

foreach($collection as $item){
    var_dump($collection);
    echo $item . PHP_EOL;
}
unset($item);
```

... prints the expected result every time.

Answer (score 2):

variable `$number` is initialized even after loop  , you need to break the reference by `unset`

this code works properly:

```
<?php
$numbers = array('zero', 'one', 'two', 'three');

foreach($numbers as &$number)
{
  $number = strtoupper($number);
}

print_r($numbers);
unset($number);

$texts = array();
foreach($numbers as $number)
{
  $texts[] = $number;
}

print_r($texts);
?>
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.unset.php

> When you unset the reference, you just break the binding between variable name and variable content. This does not mean that variable content will be destroyed.
>
> ...think about this as analogous to the Unix unlink call.

http://uk.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

> **Warning about foreach**
>
> Reference of a $value and the last array element remain even after the foreach loop. It is recommended to destroy it by unset().

Answer (score 2):

You should break the reference after the first loop.

```
foreach($numbers as &$number)
{
   $number = strtoupper($number);
}    
unset($number);
```

as stated in [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

> Warning   Reference of a $value and the last array element remain
> even after the foreach loop. It is recommended to destroy it by
> unset().

Also, if you use var_dump() instead of print_r(), you'll notice that the last element of array after the first loop is a reference:

```
array(4) {
[0]=>
string(4) "ZERO"
[1]=>
string(3) "ONE"
[2]=>
string(3) "TWO"
[3]=>
&string(5) "THREE"
}
```

If you follow Stefan Gehrig's comments on question, there is a link that perfectly explains this behaviour:
http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/141-References-and-foreach.html