# Can you explain this odd behaviour with repeated values after looping with a reference?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Strange behaviour after loop by reference - Is this a PHP bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220399/strange-behaviour-after-loop-by-reference-is-this-a-php-bug)

#### [ideone](http://ideone.com/zTv2i)

#### code:

```
<?php
$arr = array(array(1),array(2),array(3));
foreach($arr as &$i) {
    print_r($i);
}
foreach($arr as $i) {
    print_r($i);
}
```

#### output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2
)
Array
(
    [0] => 3
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2
)
```

I know I just need to put an `unset($i)` after the first loop to fix it, but I can't really figure out what would cause the `2` to be repeated. It always seems to be the last value that is overwritten with the 2nd to last value. It doesn't seem to happen when the array items are primitives ('scalar' in PHP).

I've ran into this problem a few times with reused variables when someone forgets to unset a reference. Really confused me the first time.

## Duplicates

- [Strange behavior Of foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969243/strange-behavior-of-foreach)
- [Understanding foreach logic with references - Why is the 1st element being changed to 'two', the 2nd to 'three', and the third to 'three3'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8901861/understanding-foreach-logic-with-references-why-is-the-1st-element-being-chang)
- [PHP Foreach Pass by Reference: Last Element Duplicating? (Bug?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220399/strange-behaviour-after-loop-by-reference-is-this-a-php-bug)

Comment: I answered almost exactly this question with a very detailed explanation just yesterday... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8901861/understanding-foreach-logic-with-references-why-is-the-1st-element-being-chang/8901999#8901999

Comment: @MarkBaker: Your answer here was more clear: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4969286/65387 Thanks.

Comment: Hopefully, between the two sets of answers you'll have the answer to your question

Comment: @MarkBaker: Yeah, I think I see what's going on now. Was just curious. Not fond of the scoping in PHP at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your second loop is modifying the value of $arr[2] with each iteration (because after the first loop finished, $i is left as a reference to $arr[2]).  So, as the second loop runs it assigns each element of $arr in turn to $arr[2], then prints the result.