# foreach change last element

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, php-5.3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Strange behavior Of foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969243/strange-behavior-of-foreach)

Why PHP sometimes change last element of array?

I have a array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a_
    [1] => b_
    [2] => c_
    [3] => d_
)
```

When I try print out all emenets. And output is:

```
a_
b_
c_
c_
```

Full code is:

```
<?
$a = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');

foreach ($a as &$value)
    $value = "{$value}_";

print_r($a);

foreach ($a as $value) {
    echo "$value\n";
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Either using a different variable name in your second loop or unsetting $value after your first one will solve this problem.

```
$a = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');

foreach ($a as &$value) {
    $value = "{$value}_";
}

unset($value);

print_r($a);

foreach ($a as $value) {
    echo "$value\n";
}
```

Comment: This was EXTREMEMLY helpful!  I was stumped.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like php messes up the pointer adress in your example:

Can't you write it like this:

```
<?php

    $a = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++)
        $a[$i] = "{$a[$i]}_";

    print_r($a);

    foreach ($a as $value) {
        echo "$value\n";
    }

?>
```

Comment: already explained in http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php