# Rename PHP array keys in object oriented functions

Tags: php, arrays

This may seem like a trivial question, but I'm not sure how to search for this? Let me explain my problem in situ...

I currently have this object oriented php function...

```
class Gallery extends Methods {

    /**
     * Output image attachment source
     * @return void
    */
    public function img_src ($image_id,$size) {
        $attachment_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, $size );
        return $attachment_src;
    }

}
```

Then I'm creating these vars foreach of my images..

```
<?php

  $img['thumbnail'] = Gallery::img_src( $image->ID, 'thumbnail' );
  $img['medium']    = Gallery::img_src( $image->ID, 'medium'    );
  $img['large']     = Gallery::img_src( $image->ID, 'large'     );
  $img['full-size'] = Gallery::img_src( $image->ID, 'full-size' );

  exit( '<pre>' . print_r( $img['full-size'], true ));

?>
```

The exit pre print_r call above, see output below...

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/jorge-hernandez-farguell_0067.jpg
    [1] => 5760
    [2] => 3840
    [3] => 
)
```

So currently if I wanted to output the width which is array key 1, I have to do this...

```
$img['full-size'][1];
$img['full-size'][2];
$img['full-size'][3];
```

The current above array key structure is confusing because the integer keys mean nothing. So my million dollar question is.. can I some how rename my array keys so my array outputs like this...

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/jorge-hernandez-farguell_0067.jpg
    [width] => 5760
    [height] => 3840
    [3] => 
)
```

and in turn, I would like to be able to outout the data like this...

```
<?=$img['full-size']['url']?>
<?=$img['full-size']['width']?>
<?=$img['full-size']['height']?>
```

Can anyone help me with adjusting my top attach_src function to do this? Or can this not be done?

Thanks in advance!
x

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src

Comment: I'm not sure if `attach_src()` is wrong or `img_src()` is the typo but please fix it as it is very confusing.

Comment: Yes that is a typo, thank you for spotting @MonkeyZeus

Comment: How about simply `return array('url' => $attachment_src[0], 'width' => $attachment_src[1] etc` in `img_src()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know what the indexes are in reference to, you can just rename them before you return the result. Check out the answer at:
[How to rename array keys in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605143/how-to-rename-array-keys-in-php)

Comment: Also, I looked at this and totally missed the obvious. Thank you :-)