# Using a reference when converting a string array to an integer array in PHP causes unexpected output?

Tags: php, arrays, string, integer, type-conversion

Say we have this array of strings:

```
$arrString = ["1", "2", "3"];
```

One traditional way of converting the values to integers are like so:

```
foreach ($arrString as $key => $value)
    $arrString[$key] = (int) $arrString[$key];

echo var_dump($arrString);
```

This outputs:

```
array(3) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(3) }
```

Much expected. However, I believe using a reference is a much quicker way of getting the same work done:

```
foreach ($arrString as &$strValue)
    $strValue = (int) $strValue;

 echo var_dump($arrString);
```

Well guess what it outputs?

```
array(3) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> &int(3) }
```

Which is to say it assigned the last value as a reference to an int. This always happens to the last element when using a reference in the loop (even when there's just one element), and it also happens irrespectively if I use the (int) cast or PHP's settype- and intval functions.

It beats me; Why is this happening? And should I really care?

Comment: fyi- `array_walk($arr, 'intval');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should care, and it's been explained many times before here on SO (and there's an explicit warning in the PHP documentation)

Do

```
unset($strValue);
```

after the loop

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969243/strange-behavior-of-foreach/4969286#4969286) for an explanation

**EDIT**

[Reference](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

with quote:

> **Warning**
>
> Reference of a *$value* and the last array element remain even after the *foreach* loop. It is recommended to destroy it by unset().