# PHP foreach without reference misses elements

Tags: php, foreach

I tend to find that when using foreach stuctures without using references, some elements of the array are missing.

```
$array = array();

/* ... */

$array[] = 1;
$array[] = 2;
$array[] = 3;

/* ... */

print_r($array); /* print_r always shows all elements */

foreach ($array as $element) { /* missing elements */ }
foreach ($array as &$element) { /* does a fine job */ }
```

I have had three independent occurrences of this in my code. The fix is easy (add &), but it sounds like a bug either in PHP or in my setup...

Are more people experiencing this? What is the problem?

PHP 5.4.12

---

**EDIT**

Case:

```
$a = array();
$a[] = 1;
$a[] = 2;
$a[] = 3;

foreach ($a as &$e)
{
    echo $e;
}

echo '<br>';

foreach ($a as $e)
{
    echo $e;
}
```

Output:

```
123
122
```

Comment: I dont think so man... are you expecting element to start at 1 instead of 0?

Comment: what about showing us what is currently executed in the foreach?

Comment: Could you please create an exact example which shows the problem?

Comment: You should not use `$array = [];` just remove this line!

Comment: Your test code produces "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in php shell code on line 1" because it should be $a=array();

Comment: Other than that... Runs as you say. Maybe someone has a good explanation, I don't yet.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Pass by reference in foreach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307409/php-pass-by-reference-in-foreach)

Comment: There's a reason why the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) warns about using by reference in a foreach loop

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969243/strange-behavior-of-foreach/4969286#4969286 for a full explanation of exactly what's happening

Answer (score 0):

Just confirmed.

```
<?php
  $x[]=1;
  $x[]=2;
  $x[]=3;
  $x[]=4;
  foreach($x as $y) {
    var_dump($y);
  }
?>
```

int(1) int(2) int(3) int(4)

Comment: I figured out when the oddity is reproduced, please try again!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this issue is solved in PHP ver. 5.6.10.

I have an array with 8 elements. Here is the var_dump:

array(8) { [0]=> string(18) "lname is required." [1]=> string(18) "fname is required." [2]=> string(18) "email is required." [3]=> string(22) "password1 is required." [4]=> string(22) "password2 is required." [5]=> string(44) "First Name must be letters and numbers only." [6]=> string(43) "Last Name must be letters and numbers only." [7]=> string(22) "Invalid e-mail address" }

I print out the array using this code:

foreach ($_SESSION['error'] as $error) {
        print $error . "
\n";
    }

My MAMP localhost uses **PHP ver. 5.6.10** and the result is **perfect**:

"lname is required.
fname is required.
email is required.
password1 is required.
password2 is required.
First Name must be letters and numbers only.
Last Name must be letters and numbers only.
Invalid e-mail address"

My remote server uses **PHP ver. 5.3** and in this case the server **prints only the first element**:

"lname is required."

When I changed the code as Taco suggested (foreach ($_SESSION['error'] as &$error)) the ver. 5.3. also gave the good (and expected) result.