# forEach skips last element in loop

Tags: php

I'm looping over a `countries` object. However, when I reference that object I notice that the second to last element is duplicated, while the last element is skipped. Uruguay appears twice, while America does not appear at all.:

```
foreach($countries as &$country){
    $country->keywords = array_merge(array($country->name),$country->synonyms);
    var_dump($country->key);
}

var_dump('-----------------------------------------');

foreach($countries as $country){
    var_dump($country->key);
}

exit;
```

And my output. Scroll all the way to the bottom to see `uruguay` now appears twice:

```
string(7) "algeria"
string(9) "argentina"
string(9) "australia"
string(7) "belgium"
string(6) "bosnia"
string(8) "cameroon"
string(5) "chile"
string(8) "columbia"
string(9) "costarica"
string(5) "ivory"
string(7) "croatia"
string(8) "ecquador"
string(7) "england"
string(6) "france"
string(7) "germany"
string(5) "ghana"
string(6) "greece"
string(8) "honduras"
string(4) "iran"
string(5) "italy"
string(5) "japan"
string(6) "mexico"
string(11) "netherlands"
string(7) "nigeria"
string(8) "portugal"
string(6) "russia"
string(5) "korea"
string(5) "spain"
string(11) "switzerland"
string(7) "uruguay"
string(7) "america"
string(41) "-----------------------------------------"
string(7) "algeria"
string(9) "argentina"
string(9) "australia"
string(7) "belgium"
string(6) "bosnia"
string(8) "cameroon"
string(5) "chile"
string(8) "columbia"
string(9) "costarica"
string(5) "ivory"
string(7) "croatia"
string(8) "ecquador"
string(7) "england"
string(6) "france"
string(7) "germany"
string(5) "ghana"
string(6) "greece"
string(8) "honduras"
string(4) "iran"
string(5) "italy"
string(5) "japan"
string(6) "mexico"
string(11) "netherlands"
string(7) "nigeria"
string(8) "portugal"
string(6) "russia"
string(5) "korea"
string(5) "spain"
string(11) "switzerland"
string(7) "uruguay"
string(7) "uruguay"
```

Comment: Could you give us the definitions of your data?

Comment: You may want to try to `unset($country)` after the first loop. References have minor gotchas.

Comment: @Maerlyn not unset, reset the array `$countries`

Comment: Hit by the `by reference` in a foreach loop

Comment: @pce - nope, unset(), Maerlyn is quite right

Comment: I'm fully aware of how `by reference` works in a foreach loop, look at the names against the comments in your linked article.... explain how reset will help and unset won't?

Comment: @pce reset has no meaning in context with foreach, as it uses it's own array-internal pointer, not the one stored together in the array in the zval.

Comment: @R.Barzell, not sure what you mean by definitions.

Comment: @Maerlyn, `unset` destroys the array

Comment: @pce, `reset` does not solve the issue

Comment: @AakilFernandes `unset($country);` after the end of your first `foreach()` loop will __not__ destroy the array, it will fix your problem

Comment: @MarkBaker, I ran `unset` on `countries` instead of `country`, my bad. your answer is correct

Comment: @AakilFernandes yeah, i deleted my comments. i already linked to a blog entry about references and foreach and *unset*, but i accidentally thought of another issue :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($countries as &$country){
    $country->keywords = array_merge(array($country->name),$country->synonyms);
    var_dump($country->key);
}
unset($country);

var_dump('-----------------------------------------');

foreach($countries as $country){
    var_dump($country->key);
}
```

Comment: It works because you're unsetting a reference, not the actual array entry; otherwise the reference is still pointing to the last entry in your array when you start iterating over that array again, so it overwrites the entry pointed to by that reference

Comment: See my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969243/strange-behavior-of-foreach/4969286#4969286) for an explanation