# Strange behavior with foreach

Tags: php, foreach, reference

Why does this:

```
<?php

$a = array( 1, 2, 3 );

echo "First iteration:\n";

foreach ( $a as $b => &$c ) { 
    echo $c . "\n";
}

echo "\nSecond iteration:\n";

foreach ( $a as $b => $c ) { 
    echo $c . "\n";
}
```

Produce this:

```
First iteration:
1
2
3

Second iteration:
1
2
2
```

I'm expecting the second iteration to produce the same result as the first, shouldn't I?

Observe that the difference is "element by reference" in the first foreach.

Comment: Can you do var_dump($a) after each iteration to see if the original array itself has somehow changed ?

Comment: [strange behavior of foreach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969243/strange-behavior-of-foreach/4969286#4969286)