# Manipulate an array when looping

Tags: php, arrays

So `$tr['tree']` is an array. `$dic` is an array stored as key values. I want to add the key `source` to that those arrays. It looks like the following code doesn't work as expected as I'm guessing `$dic` is a new instance of the array object inside `$tr['tree']`.

```
foreach($tr['tree'] as $dic){
    $dic['source'] = $tr['source']." > ".$dic['name'];
}
```

Note, I'm coming from python where this would work brilliantly. So how would I do this in PHP?

Comment: Add an ampersand to tell php you that it should loop by reference, e.g. `foreach($tr['tree'] as &$dic)`. Here is your startpoint: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Comment: Add that as an answer and I'll upvote it and accept it :)

Comment: I think this is a pretty good one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30263129/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

foreach() creates copies of the items you're looping on, so `$dic` in the loop is detached from the array. If you want to modify the parent array, the safe method is to use:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
   $array[$key] = $new_value;
}
```

You could use a reference:

```
foreach($array as &$value) {
                  ^---
     $value = $new_value;
}
```

but that can lead to stupidly-hard-to-find bugs later. `$value` will REMAIN a reference after the foreach terminates. If you re-use that variable name later on for other stuff, you'll be modifying the array, because the var still points at it.

Comment: For the strange behaviour: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4969243 this is a good example. (And if you would want to go "deeper" how it works with `is_ref` and so on: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10057671) (<- If you want take it in your answer as examples/references)

Comment: In the example I gave I needed to modify the child array. What would a safe way be there?

Comment: `$array[$key][$childkey]`... since you're dealing with the original array for the assignment, doesn't matter how/what you do inside the loop - you'd be modifying the "real" data. of course, if you start doing silly things like adding/removing things in `$array` itself, then the you start entering undefined territory

Comment: @MarcB Not necessarily *undefined* -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/14854568/3933332 you just have to know what PHP does