# Strange foreach loop behaviour in PHP

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

Can somebody explain why the second foreach loop outputs the item with ID = 2 twice?

The '&' in the first loop is intended to alter the real object and not a copy. When I change field name $value in second loop to something else, it works as expected but I would like to understand, why it comes to this output.

```
$a = array("ID" => "1");
$b = array("ID" => "2");
$d = array("ID" => "3");
$c = array($a, $b, $d);

foreach ($c as &$value)
{
    $value['foo'] = rand(0, 10000);
}

print_r($c);

foreach ($c as $value)
{
    print_r($value);
}
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [foo] => 5673
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 2
            [foo] => 5421
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 3
            [foo] => 149
        )

)
Array
(
    [ID] => 1
    [foo] => 5673
)
Array
(
    [ID] => 2
    [foo] => 5421
)
Array
(
    [ID] => 2
    [foo] => 5421
)
```

Comment: What is `print_a()` function?

Comment: Because `$value` is a reference.

Comment: duplicate question

Comment: "print_a" is my personal "print_r" function, it just adds "<pre>"-tags, so the output is well formatted in the webbrowser. I just edited it to "print_r" because for the question it is not relevant.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From one of the SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969243/strange-behavior-of-foreach)

This is well-documented PHP behaviour
See the [warning](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) on the foreach page of php.net

> **Warning**
>
> Reference of a *$value* and the last array element remain even after the *foreach* loop. It is recommended to destroy it by unset().

So your code should be:

```
<?php
$a = array("ID" => "1");
$b = array("ID" => "2");
$d = array("ID" => "3");
$c = array($a, $b, $d);

foreach ($c as &$value)
{
    $value['foo'] = rand(0, 10000);
}

print_r($c);

unset($value);

foreach ($c as $value)
{
    print_r($value);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [foo] => 6465
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 2
            [foo] => 4562
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 3
            [foo] => 2629
        )

)
Array
(
    [ID] => 1
    [foo] => 6465
)
Array
(
    [ID] => 2
    [foo] => 4562
)
Array
(
    [ID] => 3
    [foo] => 2629
)
```

Comment: Cool, you copypasted an existing answer.

Comment: @downvoters: dare to specify the reason?

Comment: @u_mulder I made link to that post already. Is it illegal to quote? and also I have added the answer specific to him!