# Understanding PHP dangling array references

Tags: php, arrays

Here is the code I've found on the web:

```
$array = [1, 2, 3];
echo implode(',', $array), "\n";

foreach ($array as &$value) {}    // by reference
echo implode(',', $array), "\n";

foreach ($array as $value) {}     // by value (i.e., copy)
echo implode(',', $array), "\n";
```

I want to understand why this happens.
Can someone explain what happens with the reference each step. I know about this "bug" but I want to understand why is this happening.

BTW The output is:

```
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,2
```

Comment: @Mark Baker You can refer him to the existing question.

Comment: I got the link up there. The answer seems helpful i just need time to understand it.

Comment: Can you comment the link here? It will be useful for me as well as others.

Comment: [strange-behavior-of-foreach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969243/strange-behavior-of-foreach?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the link suggestion.